# Ask if it is possible to have two policies for one device

Tags: android-management-api

Ask if it is possible to have two policies for one device.

I ask if there is a way to apply the default policy in a *specific situation.

*specific situation : (Assumed) A policy is applied when the data communication of the device is not possible.

If data communication is running smoothly, the last B policy received is applied.

If you want to change the policy on the user's device, it seems possible to change the policy only when data communication is normal.
However, I would like to apply policy A in case data communication is blocked for a device to which policy B is applied.

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t possible to change the policy when the device is offline. We suggest using [policy compliance rules](https://developers.google.com/android/management/compliance) to take action in case the device comes out of compliance while it is offline.
When the device is online, you can change the current policy on a device by calling [devices.patch()](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/patch) and setting the `policyName` field to the new policy.

Sample code:

```
deviceBody = {
    'policyName':'enterprises/LC0xxxx/policies/policy_2'
}

androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().patch(name='enterprises/LC0xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx', updateMask='policyName', body = deviceBody).execute()
```